# Nats Name vs Durable Name

Tags: nats.io

In Nats go client we can setup a consumer with js.AddConsumer(). This function takes a ConsumerConfig.

```
// ConsumerConfig is the configuration of a JetStream consumer.
type ConsumerConfig struct {
Durable         string          `json:"durable_name,omitempty"`
Name            string          `json:"name,omitempty"`
Description     string          `json:"description,omitempty"`
...
```

Now the question. What is the difference vs Durable and Name in this config?
The Nats CLI doesn't mention separate names. There is only a "Consumer name" which is equivalent to the "Durable Name".

And if I set Durable and Name to different values I get this error:

Code:
400
ErrorCode:
10017 = 0x2721
Description:
"consumer name in subject does not match durable name in request"